# Create project that is not in the default path in DataSpell

Tags: jetbrains-ide, dataspell

I tried the new DataSpell today, but fail to create a project. Every time I try to attach a directory, it has been marked as a library. And it seems like the Project is always in

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\DataSpell2021.3\projects\workspace
```

What's more, the intended project root folder (i.e., Test_2) is marked as a `Module`,

[image]

What's more, I can not mark the directory as well as all the subdrectories within it:

[image]
Does anyone know how to create a `PyCharm` like project in DataSpell?

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: Still the same, are there DataSpell developers on SO?